# Matplotlib Plots: Bold font face not working for Helvetica Neue but works fine with Arial

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am having trouble setting the bold face for 'Helvetica Neue' font while using matplotlib plot. It works file with 'Arial' but somehow bold face for 'Helvetica Neue' doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Here the python code I am using:

```
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 14
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 14

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
#mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Arial Narrow']
#mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Arial']
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Helvetica Neue']
mpl.rcParams["font.weight"] = "bold"
mpl.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"
mpl.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 16

params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular'}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

.
.
.
.

axes.set_xlabel("hello world")
axes.set_ylabel('hello world  1x10$^{555}$ (unit)')
```

Here are the attached images:
[image][image]

Comment: Do you HAVE a font called "Helvetica Neue"?  It looks to me like it has defaulted to Arial.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think so as I typically use it in word doc and latex. How should I check, and if not, how can I install so matplot can use it?

Comment: Latex usually has its own font collection.  You can get the list by `import matplotlib.font_manager` / `from pprint import pprint` / `pprint( matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist )`

Comment: I ran the code you mentioned and it does give me this for helvetica:
<Font 'Helvetica Neue' (HelveticaNeue.ttc) normal normal 400 normal>

hmm.. Should it be ".ttf" and not ".ttc". All the fonts with ".ttf" extension seem to be working.

Comment: But is a bold variant listed?  It can't invent bold unless there is a specific font.

Comment: Oh yes, it is missing bold. Arial and Arial Narrow has separate entry for bold. How can I get one? Thanks!

Comment: Alright! Finally! I managed to convert the .ttc to .ttf format using online data converter for helvetical fonts (https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack). Pasted .ttf converted files into <python install patl>/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf  and then removed the matplotlib cache using rm -rf ~/.matplotlib/fontlist.cache and rm -rf ~/.matplotlib/fontlist.json and then re-ran my code. It worked all well

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working finally. Here are the steps I took.

1. Convert the desired .ttc font files to .ttf using the [online font
   converter](https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack).
2. Then paste these .ttf converted files into >>

   ```
       <python install patl>/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
   ```
3. Remove the matplotlib cache (important step to see the changes) using

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.matplotlib/fontlist.cache
   ```

   and

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.matplotlib/fontlist.json
   ```
4. Re-run the same code as in the question. It worked all well!

Comment: I have the same situation with Helvetica fontweight='bold' not working, and this solution is not working. I am using  Mac OS. Any ideas?